# Simple examples showing the HTML parsing differences across web browsers?

Tags: html, browser, cross-browser, html-parsing

Before HTML5, there were some differences among browsers in terms of "HTML understanding".

E.g. [`<foo<bar>` can either be parsed as two tags or as one tag.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/HTML5/HTML5_Parser)

Currently, I just tried

```
<ol<li>hello
```

But I didn't see any difference among IE, Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

are there still parsing differences among different browsers? If so, could you show some simple but common examples?

Comment: That example remains current.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with HTML5

Comment: Any time you do something broken, expect the unexpected.

Comment: @BoltClock Could you show the concrete differences?

Comment: @Pumbaa80: They decided to play with parsing rules in HTML5, so it looks like a browser can actually be considered non-conformant to HTML5 if it parses invalid code in a particular way. Crazy, I know.

Comment: @BoltClock I was trying to say that, no matter what the specs say, Browsers will still do their thing. And their parsers are unlikely to make a difference between proper HTML4/HTML5/Tag Soup. Thanks for the interesting info though. Funny to see that compliant parsers [may just abort](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/parsing.html#parse-error).

Comment: Looks like the Mozilla article is outdated. Webkit now correctly handles your example: http://jsfiddle.net/wbaAq/

Comment: @Pumbaa80: Remember XHTML? Good times.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 defines error handling and error recovery for malformed HTML [0]. All of the latest versions of the major browsers now have an HTML5 parser, which conforms to this spec. These HTML5 parsers were developed while checking the test suite to make sure they do the right thing. If there are any differences between modern browsers then it should be considered a bug and reported to the relevant browser vendor. I don't know of any current bugs in this area off the top of my head.

[0] http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/parsing.html